# Screencast with avconv cuts off last 5 seconds of audio

Tags: 12.04, avconv, screencast

I'm trying to record a screencast using avconv (installed from official repo). All seems to work OK, except one thing: Always, the last 5 seconds from my mic audio are dropped from the final video.

I use this command:

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 10 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 9 -c:v libx264 "$HOME/screencast_001.mkv"
```

My output file is great, exactly as needed, except that ALWAYS the last 5 seconds of AUDIO is discarded. Video is OK until the end. Any hint about what can I do to fix it?

My system is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64 bits, all up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are ending the recording by pressing `Ctrl+C` in the terminal. This ends the program without letting it finish what it has started. What that means is that some of the audio just hasn't been processed yet. The issue is with the processor time, you have a lot of load going on with video conversion on the fly, and thus audio gets buffered and then processed quickly as a batch of some seconds. When you terminate the program, there is always some audio left in the buffer that hasn't been processed yet.

One simply approach would be to just wait a little bit before terminating the recording.

If you are open to using other software, you can also use RecordMyDesktop, which generates Ogg+Theora videos and works quite nicely on my system.